# Binary tree for 2 elements

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

I want to understand Binary Search for 2 element list made of 1,2. I draw a tree as below. Is it correct?

[image]

If I want to search for an element 2, it will make 2 comparisons. If I want to search for an element 22, it will also make 2 comparisons. But according to formula Θ(lg n), with n=2, it should make only one comparison in worst case. I'm not able to connect these 2 facts. Please help me. (For any even number of elements, I'm not able to draw tree. Because at some point, left side has one node and right side has 2 nodes)

Comment: The formula $\Theta(\log n)$ defines a class of functions. It has no particular value at any given point.

Comment: So you mean to say Θ(lg n) is just a classification. The exact number of comparisons will not necessarily match with values of Θ(lg n).

Comment: Not exactly. My point is that $\Theta(\log n)$ doesn’t specify any particular value at any single $n$. It only stands in for a function growing logarithmically. The function could be $\log n$, or $2\log n$, or $\log n + \log \log n$ - the notation $\Theta(\log n)$ doesn’t specify which.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Diagram of even numbers has really baffled me. Would you please give one example diagram for lets say n=8?

Comment: Perhaps the Wikipedia entry on binary search trees contains such diagrams.

Comment: I just checked Wikipedia. They are all with odd numbers. Even all the online article I read focus on odd numbers. Looks like people want to shy away from even numbers. :)

Comment: @gmailuser, for every binary search tree with odd number of nodes, you can just remove its largest node. You will get a binary search tree with even number of nodes. Of course, there are many binary search trees with even number of nodes.

Comment: On the other hand, it might be an interesting observation that binary search trees with even number of nodes appear more than those of odd number of nodes in reality. For example, when the left tree and right tree has the same number of nodes.

Comment: @Apass.Jack would you please point me to some example of binary search tree with even number of nodes?

Comment: @gmailuser, please go to https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BST.html. Write a number in the first field and hit "insert". Repeat it for whatever times you want. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. @Apass.Jack your tool is really helpful.

Comment: I am glad to be helpful. All credits go to [David Galles](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/), who creates and runs the tool. His [Data Structure Visualizations sites](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html) are immensely useful!